# selenium test stuck

Tags: selenium

i would like to run a test html suite on a debian server with xvfb. 
the process stuck at 'Launching firefox' :

```
 $ java -jar sel/selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite *firefox http://www.google.com ./ts1.html ./tr1.html 
 14:35:41.996 INFO - Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 11.2-b01
 14:35:41.997 INFO - OS: Linux 2.6.18-xen i386
 14:35:42.004 INFO - v1.0.1 [2696], with Core v@VERSION@ [@REVISION@]
 14:35:42.076 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
 14:35:42.077 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
 14:35:42.077 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
 14:35:42.078 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
 14:35:42.081 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
 14:35:42.081 INFO - Started org.mortbay.jetty.Server@ef22f8
 14:35:42.165 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
 14:35:45.832 INFO - Launching Firefox...
```

at this time i can create a screenshot of my xvfb display, i can see the browser window, but it is very poor... :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciR5Q.png]

the same testsuite with the same selenium-server.jar works perfectly on my ubuntu desktop...

does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

thanks, 
gg

Answer (score 0):

ups. it was a permission problem. the user who tried to run the selenium test did not have enough permission.